React-router errorElement does not catch errors
When using react-router 6.18 the top level errorElement is not rendered on error. I define my routes like this:
Routes.tsx
const routes = [
  {
    element:(
      <>
        <h1>WRAPPER</h1>
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    errorElement: <h1>ERROR PAGE</h1>,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: (
          <>
          <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
          <Outlet />
          </>
        ),
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            //loader: () => {throwAuthenticationError()},
            element: <><h2>CHILD PAGE</h2>{throwAuthenticationError()}</>
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);

index.tsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { router } from 'Routes';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>MY APP</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>

and use the following function to throw the error:
export default function throwAuthenticationError(errorMessage: string, error?: unknown): never {
    console.error(errorMessage);
 
    if(error) {
        console.error("Caught Error:");
        console.error(error);
    }
 
    throw new Response("You were logged out", { status: 401 });
}

When I throw the error in the loader the error element is rendered as expected. However when I throw it in the element Uncaught runtime error overlay is rendered and when I close it there is just a blank screen underneath. Why is that? And how can I fix it? I have also tried to include the errorElement in each route but it does not seem to have an effect.
Here is the whole error message:
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR

[object Response]
handleError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:667010:67
@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:667029:18

Console output:
[Error] [object Response]
    __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:765864)
    (anonymous function) (bundle.js:767119)
    Global Code (bundle.js:767121)

